How can I parse a Code 128 if my scanner does not give a check digit
At a customer we have following barcode:

This is a medicinal product. With a scanner app of Cognex, the type is recognized as 'Code 128 (GS1)'.
However when scanned this barcode with our Honeywell scanners (type 3310G), I only receive the visible digits and no check digit.
Question now is, is this effectively a Code 128 or another type? Because when looking for ways to parse and verify the format of the digits using Code 128 calculation (modulo 105), I don't see a way to use the calculation on this code.
Thank you for the help!

The check digit is a mandatory part of Code128.  Your scanner wouldn't have returned anything if the check digit didn't match, so there's no need for you to verify it yourself.

Ok, at pharmacies we have (French) CIP13 codes, which is one of the possible type of Code128. For that codetype we can verify with the scanned digits if it's a CIP13 (the 13th character is the check digit). The code in the photo might just be a Code128 and not a particular 'subtype' ?
